# Superposition of two fixed div on a sticky scroll

Tags: javascript, css

i'm trying to have a sticky div for my website.
I'd like it to pass over a fixed image and then to be fixed on the top of this fixed image, then the content coming after would past over the sticky div.
I kind of succeed to do all this, except that the sticky div is passing below the fixed image.
I can't find what is the problem, I guess it's not so complicated but my limits are not very high.
Thank you anyway,

Here's the code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 309) {
        $(".sticker").addClass("fixed");
    } else {
        $(".sticker").removeClass("fixed");
    }
});
</script>
<style>
.sticker {
height:80px;
padding-left:50px;
margin-left: 242px;
width:800px;
background:red;
display:block;
z-index:2;
}

.fixed {
position:fixed;
top:50px;

}

.top {
height:350px;
width:800px;
}

.img-fix {
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 800px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:blue;
    z-index:1;
}

.container {
    background-color:green; 
    padding-right:60px; 
    padding-left:60px; 
    width:800px; 
    height:800px; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 200px; 
    top:445px; 
    z-index:3;}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="img-fix"></div>
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="sticker"></div>

<div class="container">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "position: relative;" to .sticker:

```
.sticker {
    position: relative;
    // the rest of your CSS
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lemoncurry/geoc3rtw/